# HTML li element will not except

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am going through this signalR example at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio.

Everything works where the Send button sends the user and the message to the server side signalR chat Hub.  Then the Hub sends the user and message back to all the clients "ReceiveMessage" function callback on the Hub connection object in the Javascript.
I have a bunch of console.log statements showing the user and message made it up to the server and back.

But there is this encoded message variable that you assign to an li element which gets added back to a  element in the DOM.

But in the Javascript if I try to assign the encodedMsg to the li execution just stops.  If I assign the static value 'Hello' it continues exection and works.

This is the signalR "ReceiveMessages" callback:

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
console.log("In client side: ReceiveMessage");
console.log(`user: ${user}`);
console.log(`message: ${message}`);
var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
console.log(`msg: ${msg}`);
var encodeMsg = user + " says " + msg;
console.log(`encodeMsg: ${encodeMsg}`);
var li = document.createElement("li");
console.log(`li: ${li}`);
li.textContent = 'Hello'; //encodedMsg;
console.log(`li.textContent: ${li.textContent}`);
document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

Here the li.textContent gets a value:

[image]

But if I try to add the actual encodedMsg it seems to just stop execution:

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    console.log("In client side: ReceiveMessage");
    console.log(`user: ${user}`);
    console.log(`message: ${message}`);
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    console.log(`msg: ${msg}`);
    var encodeMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    console.log(`encodeMsg: ${encodeMsg}`);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    console.log(`li: ${li}`);
    /*li.textContent = 'Hello'; //encodedMsg; */
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    console.log(`li.textContent: ${li.textContent}`);
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    });
```

[image]

I am not great at JavaScript.  Does anyone see why it does't want to assign the dynamic encodedMsg var to the li textContent?

Comment: Isn't that a typo? `encodeMsg` vs `encodedMsg`

Comment: Yes it was a typo thank you.  I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. You defined your variable as `encodeMsg` (note missing *d*) but you are using it as `encodedMsg`